# Sort html table according to list of checkboxes in table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, checkbox, html-table

In my html table there one column ("IsReserved") is list of Checkboxes some are checked and some not.
When user click on IsReserved header than table is sorted by it.
Means on first click in asc order and on second click desc order.
I want this problem is done by usig javascript or jquery and if any other then please.

In short i want to sort table according checkboxes in "IsReserved" column
Thanks.

```js
function sortTable(f, n) {
        var rows = $('#tab tbody  tr').get();

        rows.sort(function (a, b) {

            var A = $(a).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
            var B = $(b).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
            $("input:checkbox").attr("id")
            parseInt($(a).data("sort"));

            if (A < B) {
                return -1 * f;
            }
            if (A > B) {
                return 1 * f;
            }
            return 0;
        });

        $.each(rows, function (index, row) {
            $('#tab').children('tbody').append(row);
        });
    }

    var f_sl = 1;
    var f_nm = 1;
    //sort table by name
    $("#name").click(function () {
        f_sl *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_sl, n);

    });

    //sort table by code
    $("#code").click(function () {
        f_nm *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_nm, n);
    });

    //sort table by category
    $("#category").click(function () {
        f_nm *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_nm, n);
    });

    //sort table by saleprice
    $("#saleprice").click(function () {
        f_nm *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_nm, n);
    });

    //sort table by lead time
    $("#leadtime").click(function () {
        f_nm *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_nm, n);
    });

    //sort table by qty per unit
    $("#qtu").click(function () {
        f_nm *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_nm, n);
    });

    //sort table by current stock
    $("#currentstock").click(function () {
        f_nm *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_nm, n);
    });

    //sort table by record level
    $("#recordlevel").click(function () {
        f_nm *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_nm, n);
    });

    //end of sort table
```

```html
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: ProductViewList">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="calign leftbordernone" style="width:50px">
                                    <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("EditProduct", "Inventory")?id=' + Id}" title="Edit Product">
                                        <img src="~/Images/edit.png" height="15" width="15" alt="" />
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td class="calign leftbordernone" style="width:50px">
                                    <a data-bind="click: function () { DeleteProduct(Id); }" href="" title="Delete Product">
                                        <img src="~/Images/delete.png" height="15" width="15" alt="" />
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td class=" lalign leftbordernone" style="width:90px" data-bind="text: ProductCode"></td>
                                <td class=" lalign" data-bind="text: ProductName"></td>
                                <td class=" lalign" style="width:70px" data-bind="text: CategoryName"></td>
                                <td class=" lalign" style="text-align:center;width:40px">
                                    <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="chkbox" data-bind="checked:IsActive" />
                                </td>
                                <td class=" lalign" style="text-align:right" data-bind="text: formatPrice(SalesPrice)"></td>
                                <td class=" lalign" style="text-align:right" data-bind="text: QtyperUnit"></td>
                                <td class=" lalign" style="text-align:right" data-bind="text: LeadTime"></td>
                                <td class=" lalign" style="text-align:right" data-bind="text: CurrentStock"></td>
                                <td class=" lalign" style="text-align:right" data-bind="text: ReorderLevel"></td>
                                <td class=" lalign rightbordernone" style="text-align:center">
                                    <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="chkbox" data-bind="checked: Reserved" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Please provide your code and markup in the question specifying where are you facing a problem.

Comment: hey bro i added table code which i want to sort according to last td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to sort table according checkboxes

In order to do that, you need to compare the `checked` property of the `input` inside the columns.

In your `rows.sort` method use the comparer like this:

```
$rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var value1= $(a).find('td').eq(idx).find("input")[0].checked,
        value2 = $(b).find('td').eq(idx).find("input")[0].checked;

    return (value1 > value2); 
}
```

Where `idx` is the index of the column of the header which is clicked.

Here is a complete working demo, with sorting on multiple columns (*explanation in code comments*)...

**Snippet**:

```js
var $buttons = $('.sort'), $tab = $("#tab");

$buttons.click(function(e) {
    var self = this,
     $rows = $tab.find("tbody > tr"),
        idx = $buttons.index(this);       // index of the header which is clicked
  
    $rows.sort(function(a, b) {
        var $obj1 = $(a).find('td').eq(idx),  // which cell column based on index
            $obj2 = $(b).find('td').eq(idx),  
            value1, value2;
        
        if ($obj1.text().length > 0) {           // if the cell contains text
            value1 = $obj1.text().toUpperCase(); // use the text value
            value2 = $obj2.text().toUpperCase();
        } else {                                 // if the cell does not contain text
            value1 = $obj1.find("input")[0].checked; // use the checked property..
            value2 = $obj2.find("input")[0].checked  // .. of the input
        }

        // check if ascending or not
        if ($(self).hasClass('asc')) return (value1 > value2); 
        else return (value1 < value2); 
        
    });
    
    $(this).toggleClass('asc'); // toggle class for next ascending-descending sort
  
    // perform physical reordering
    $.each($rows, function(index, row){
        $tab.append(row);
    });
    
});
```

```css
table, th, td { border: 1px solid #ddd; border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td { padding: 4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><a href="#" class="sort asc">IsReserved</a></th>
            <th><a href="#" class="sort asc">Caption</a></th>
            <th><a href="#" class="sort asc">Other</a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>One</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" checked /></td><td>Two</td><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>Three</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="checkbox" checked /></td><td>Four</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/m6nn4ved/1/**

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [jquery table sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) for this.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#tableid").tablesorter();    
});
```

Comment: tablesorter is not sort table accor. to checkboxes]